# Embedding html in google visualization table with allowHTML

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

I'm trying to display radio buttons on a cell in my table.  I have the table displaying fine until this point, but even though I've specified to "allowHTML", it isn't picking up the html in my cell.

I call it through a wrapper:

```
var rightWrapper;
function drawVisualization() {
 rightWrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
   "chartType": "Table",
   'dataSourceUrl':'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I3N5DtdXGWFootaOCQM201K_ao2ZPWSWyw9_l7QcwQg/gviz/tq?sheet=User_my_crew&headers=1',
   'containerId':'target_table_div',
   'query':'SELECT A,B,C,D',
   'options': { "width": 700, "height": 500, "allowHTML": true }
   });
 rightWrapper.draw();
```

}

No matter what html I put in a cell, nothing is actually displaying as formatted html.  That makes me think the "allowHTML" line is wrong, but, according to the [google API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/examples), that's correct.

It may be important to note that right now I'm trying to put the info directly in my google sheet.  I've tried updating the table on the fly, but when I do even the simplest "setCell" call, it dies.

```
rightWrapper.getChart().setCell(1,2,'test'); //does not appear to execute
rightWrapper.getChart().setCell(1,2,'test','test'); //also does not appear to execute
```

Comment: `Html` not `HTML`

Comment: haha.  I swear I copied it directly from the google api... not sure how I managed to get the case wrong.